# LD_DEBUG=files for Windows Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging

I'm quite stuck on a ddl loader problem under Windows Visual Studio 2009 C++. I have a framwork which loads plugins as DLL files, unfortunatly I have no sourcecode access to the framework. The dependency walker doesn't show any errors, but the framework just says "dependencies not found" when loading the plugin. 
I'm quite unfamiliar with debugging under Windows, my next step under Linux would have been to set LD_DEBUG=files and check which DLL's/libraries are loaded.

Is something similar possible under Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [dependency walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) it has a menu entry Profile. So if you load the exe to the dependency walker and use profile you might get additional information why dll wasn't resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If the framework doesn't tell you which DLL couldn't be found, then you can manually find this out with Process Monitor.